# Find the largest and smallest numbers in a list of $n$ integers.

Tags: combinatorics

I need to use divide & conquer to find the largest and smallest numbers in a list of $n$ integers.

The answer is $a_n=2a_\frac{n}2+2$ where $a_n=$ the number of comparisons needed for a list of size $n$.

I know how to get the solution from the table, but I don't understand how they got the answer of $a_n=2a_\frac{n}2+2$. Where does the twos come from?

Comment: What does your answer mean? You want to prove why does there $a_{n}$ comparasion using divide and conquer?

Comment: I suspect one of the twos comes from finding both largest and smallest numbers, but obviously $a_2 = 1$ since in a list of two, only one comparison is needed to "find" both the largest and smallest numbers'

Comment: I don't want to sound nitpicky but I do wish you'd actually *state* the question you want the answer to.  You *say* you want to find the largest and smallest numbers.  The "$a_n = 2a_{\frac n 2} + 2$" is obviously *not* the largest and smallest number.  It's only one value, not two and it's not a number of the list.  So what actually *is* the question that this is an answer to?

Comment: @fleablood I want to know how they came up with the recurrence relation $a_n=$...for this divide and conquer question.

Comment: Then *ask* that.  You say "the answer is..."  The answer to *what* is?  I'm sorry, I am being nitpicky but it made your post hard to read.

Comment: @fleablood. I did, but I guess, not everyone understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get maximum and minimum of a list of size n, get the maximum and minimum of the two half-lists. This gives you $2a_{n/2}$. Now, to get the maximum of the complete list, see if the maximum of the $1^{st}$ half-list is greater than that of the $2^{nd}$ one. And similarly to get the minimum of the complete list. This gives you $2$ more comparisons. Thus, $a_n = 2a_{n/2}+2$.